# Domino Return Receipt Issue

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Currently, some our email users have checked their return receipt when sending to external domain or emails. Suddenly, he received a return receipt that contains the ff:

Your message was received by: Admin/Domino
Admin/Domino is my default administrator account for Lotus Domino. And secondly his recipients is not Admin/Domino.

Is this possible? As per checking of domino configuration there are no default return received by address. On my opinion, the recipient listed have their email server disabled their return receipt headers. But the question why is the message was received by Admin/Domino and there no message received on Admin/Domino email.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you, or someone else with access to the Admin/Domino id and password, open the server's mail.box database and examine the outbound message? Or open the recipients mail database and read the message?

Comment: We have already checked the users mail database file, Admin/Domino is not part of the recipient list. I will try to look into mail.box database.

Comment: As per checking on mail.box it is correct that Admin/Domino is not part of the recipient list. My only assumption the backend email server of the recipient have disabled return receipt but why is Admin/Domino sending the report?

Comment: My point in asking this question is that if you used that Admin/Domino id to open the database and then open the message in order to examine it, then that action may have caused the return receipt to be sent.

Comment: My answer is NO. We did only login as Admin/Domino when the user prompted us why did he received the return receipt mail..